# Additional SSD for MSI GE62 APACHE PRO?

Tags: memory, ssd

I am planning to get the MSI GE62 Apache Pro 15.6 FHD i7-6700HQ 8GB 1TB GTX970M 3GB laptop. I also want to get an extra 128GB of SSD (so I'll have a hybrid of 1TB HDD + 128GB SSD).

The problem is that I've never done something like this and I have no idea what to buy. I'm afraid of getting something which is not even compatible with the device, so I'm asking for your help. [This is where I will buy my SSD.](http://www.skytech.lt/vidiniai-duomenu-kaupikliai-hdd-ssd-priedai-ssd-tipo-kaupikliai-solidstate-drive-c-86_85_1407_1408.html)

- Must be compatible with the laptop specified
- Available in, or shippable to, Lithuania
- 128 GB or more (preferably without paying any more, obviously).

Please help me on deciding which one to buy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [GE62 6QF Apache Pro](https://www.msi.com/product/notebook/GE62-6QF-Apache-Pro.html#hero-overview)

You have multiple options in my opinion.

1. See if your shop offers this Laptop with a SSD.
   This would be the easiest option for you probably

---

2. Get a **M.2 SSD** - your laptop supports the new M.2 SSD's which are even faster than the regular SSD's. If a normal user really needs this is questionable but having the option is nice. It is more expensive though.
   If you want to get a M.2 SSD [**you can get it here**](http://www.skytech.lt/vidiniai-duomenu-kaupikliai-hdd-ssd-priedai-ssd-tipo-kaupikliai-solidstate-drive-c-86_85_1407_1408.html?f=s%28%29,g%28%29,p%282463%29,k%282.79,2100.00%29&frag=&fragd=0&pav=undefined&sort=5a&sand=0&grp=1&pagesize=100&page=1). Any of these should work -  pick one which suits your budget and read some reviews when you have doubts.
   You would have to add this to your laptop yourself but there are [**some How-To's on Youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwYBmsjwHhE).
   I have made some good experiences with the **Crucial** and **Intel SSD's** - they were reliable and deliver a great performance.
   **EDIT:**
   Your Laptop supports M.2 SSD's with a formfactor of 22x80mm.
   [image: M.2 Support from your Laptop]
   Source: Manual for this Laptop

But your manual does not say which M.2 Key Port it features - there are 2 different ones. [image: Different Key Ports of M.2 SSD's]
Source: [Kingston SM2280S3 120GB M.2 SATA SSD Review on legitreview.com](http://www.legitreviews.com/kingston-sm2280s3-120gb-m-2-ssd-review_148015)

Your best bet when buying a M.2 SSD is to buy one with a B&M Connector. These will fit the M.2 Port always. So your best bet would be [**this Intel 535 M.2 SSD 240 GB from Intel**](http://www.skytech.lt/ssdsckjw240h601-ssd-intel-535-240gb-sata3-mlc-540490mbs-80mm-p-241960.html) for example: [image: Intel 535 M.2 240 GB]
This will fit your laptops M.2 SSD port :)
[image: Measurements from Intel SSD]

Source: [Intel ARK Page of this article](http://ark.intel.com/products/86728/Intel-SSD-535-Series-240GB-M_2-80mm-SATA-6Gbs-16nm-MLC)

If you want to buy a SSD from another company then make sure to get one with B&M key connector and with a formfactor of 22x80mm.

---

3. Get a [**regular SSD**](http://www.skytech.lt/vidiniai-duomenu-kaupikliai-hdd-ssd-priedai-ssd-tipo-kaupikliai-solidstate-drive-c-86_85_1407_1408.html?f=s%28%29,g%28%29,p%282461%29,k%282.79,2100.00%29&frag=&fragd=0&pav=undefined&sort=5a&sand=0&grp=1&pagesize=100&page=1). Your Laptop has a built-in DVD-drive - if you are not intending to use it that much you could swap it out and replace it with a SSD. If you plan on doing that you would have to get yourself a SSD and a [**SSD/HDD Cage**](http://hddcaddy.com/en/msi-hdd-caddy/1177-msi-ge62-ssd-hdd-caddy.html). Then you would have to replace your HDD-drive with this cage which houses your SSD.

---

So it depends on which road you want to take. You can't go really wrong with many of these. My Suggestion would be a **Intel 535 M.2 SSD.** But if you want to replace your DVD-Drive with a SSD then I'd probably go for the **Crucial MX200 or BX100**

---

I hope that this helps you a bit - if you still can't decide which one to buy or which path to take then feel free to leave a comment. I'll try to update the answer accordingly :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I have some more questions: 1. There are at least two types of "cutouts" at the end of the SSD. Some of the drives has 2, and some of them has a 1 cutout. Are both of them ok with my laptop?  For example:   http://www.skytech.lt/images/large/84/630584.jpg   and http://www.skytech.lt/images/large/16/780316.jpg

Comment: 2. Do i have to do something similar like in this video ( at 6:30) ? Or can i skip this step? https://youtu.be/ArvWkGG_yu8?t=392

Comment: @Deividas Updated the answer and included some more information, glad you have asked. This should make the answer more likely to be helpful. :) You can skip the procedure at 6:30 (creating a RAID). It is not needed, but can be used to duplicate your data or make it faster to access depending on the Raid configuration. Not needed with personal use of a Laptop in my opinion. Just stick it in and install Windows if possible. If windows is preinstalled, you can clone your existing installation on the hard drive and copy it over to your new M.2 SSD. You can use a programm like Acronis to do this.