# Upgrading my laptop MSI HDD to SSD

Tags: ssd

I own a MSI Leopard GP62MVR 6RF with an standard HDD. I want to upgrade it with a new SSD but my question is: does it support **an additional** SSD or have I to **replace** its current HDD with a new SSD? And which form factor should I look for when shopping?

There's a similar question [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/additional-ssd-for-msi-ge62-apache-pro) but I'm not sure is the model are fully compatible nor if the asker will be able to have 2 drives.

Also, the 3rd response of [this thread](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=289610.0) talks about a "combo" slot but again I'm not sure if that answers my question.

Thanks!

Edit: The answer was correct and I now have a SSD and a HDD installed in my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answers up front:

> does it support an additional SSD or have I to replace its current HDD with a new SSD?

Yes, you should* be able to install an M.2 SSD alongside your current HDD (see below). You can also replace the current 2.5 inch HDD with a 2.5 inch SSD.

> And which form factor should I look for when shopping?

The M.2 SSD and 2.5 inch HDD / SSD / SSHD form factors are compatible with your laptop. I do not recommend SSHD "hybrid" drives, they're extra money for no real world gain.

---

## Explanation and source

Here's a nicely detailed teardown I found:

https://www.laptopmain.com/msi-gp62mvr-6rf-leopard-pro-disassembly-and-ram-hdd-ssd-upgrade-options/

I'm operating under the assumption that you have a "MSI Leopard GP62MVR 6RF" *PRO*, as I can't find any info on other models.

From the picture in the link, your laptop supports a 2.5 inch standard form factor HDD / SSD as well as an M.2 SSD.

Seems to me that if you took the HDD option, the M.2 slot will be empty. You can pop off the bottom of the laptop and check for yourself. If this is the case, you can definitely order a compatible M.2 SSD and install it fairly easily.

---

## Part Recommendation

I'll be happy to help you pick out a specific component if you can confirm that you have the "PRO" model of the laptop for me. Don't want to waste time researching for the wrong model laptop.

Comment: Yes, I confirm I have the pro model.
Thanks a lot for your response. For the part recommendation, I think I'll have enough with 256GB now that I know that I will be able to keep the HDD as secondary drive. Also, I don't look for the fastest SSD, I believe a standard one will have a huge impact in comparison with the current one.

Comment: @Rafaesp "Also, I don't look for the fastest SSD, I believe a standard one will have a huge impact in comparison with the current one." You are correct there my friend. Even the crappy first generation 110 GB corsair SSD I bought back in 2011 or 2012 was a night and day difference in real world performance and quality of life. Enjoy the upgrade!